# How to Replace empty string with N/A in Scala Spark?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying out an age old problem of replacing empty strings in a certain column in a Spark Scala dataframe with N/A, but to no avail.

Original Dataframe:

```
+----------+--------------+
|Testing ID|Test this Code|
+----------+--------------+
|    545242|            ""|
|    643533|          994A|
|    856563|            ""|
+----------+--------------+
```

First code I tried:

```
val a = sssd.withColumn("Test this Code", when($"Test this Code" === "", lit("N/A")).otherwise($"Test this Code"))
```

But nothing happens, zero changes observed. Hence I tried another way by using *regexp_replace*, code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val a = sssd.withColumn("Test this Code", regexp_replace(col("Test this Code"), "", "N/A"))
```

But then, the output is strange enough, its the following:

```
+----------+------------------------+
|Testing ID|          Test this Code|
+----------+------------------------+
|    545242|             N/A"N/A"N/A|
|    643533|                    994A|
|    856563|             N/A"N/A"N/A|
+----------+------------------------+
```

I went through other SO answers, but to no avail, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I suspect it's not an empty string, but actually a string of two quotes.

```
val a = sssd.withColumn("Test this Code", when($"Test this Code" === "\"\"", lit("N/A")).otherwise($"Test this Code"))
```

Comment: Brilliant!I was suspecting the same, tried multiple arrangements of  " as a string, but couldn't form the exact regex, which you gave. In python its simple, '"' (single quote double quote single quote) but that doesn't work in Scala. Thanks a lot for the quick help!